# Does feature scaling needed to be done separately for independent and dependent variable separately

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Suppose we have got a very less dataset and so I decided not to split it into train and test. As the model I am using is SVR, feature scaling should be done.
I have seen the code as X= sc_X.fit_transform(X) and Y= sc_X.fit_transform(Y). Instead just like we do fit_transform on training set and transform on test set Can the same be done on X and Y. Is fit_transform required for Y because sc_X already learns the parameters and apply them on Y

Answer (score 0):

No. First, X can have many columns whereas `y` for simple tasks contain only a single column. So using `transform()` will give error because the Scaler has learnt the information about the columns of X.

Secondly,inherently X and y have different scales. So using `transform()` will not be of any use and will introduce more discrepancy in the data.

Last, most of the times there is no need to scale the `y`. They will be automatically handled by most algorithms.

Comment: thank you... Can you just give an example of how you find it whether an algorithm does scale y automatically or we need to it manually?

Comment: and also suppose if I have not divided my dataset into X and Y instead I apply sc_X.fit_transform on the complete dataset at once will the output be equivalent to applying on individual X and Y?